# Altering Built in Substitution Strings in Oracle Apex

Tags: string, oracle, oracle-apex, substitution

I am trying to modify the LOGIN_URL and APP_ID substitution variables in oracle apex.  Does anybody know where these values are stored and/or how to edit them.

Info on substitution strings: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/HTMDB/concept_sub.htm#HTMDB03022

Comment: Curious, why would you want to edit the app_id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To edit the Login URL, go to:

- Edit application properties
- User interface
- Edit the relevant user interface (e.g. desktop)
- Set the Login URL property as required

You **cannot** edit the value returned by `APP_ID` because it returns the ID of the current APEX application, and cannot return anything else!

Comment: Not the answer I wanted to hear, but the correct one never the less.